# OUT Parameter Error in Calling MySQL Stored Procedure from Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a MySql stored procedure from the Java code in Eclipse but I get the following error. The stored procedure compiled without any error.

Import statements:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;    
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
```

Here's the java code snippet:

```
>cStmt = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{ call getEmpName(?,?)}");

>cStmt.setString(1, "xxxyyyzzz");

>cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);

>cStmt.execute();
```

Given below is the Stored procedure

```
>USE `mcaSchema`;
>DROP procedure IF EXISTS `getEmpName`;
>DELIMITER $$
>USE `mcaSchema`$$
>CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getEmpName`(IN empID int,OUT eName varchar(30)) 
>BEGIN
>>  select ename from mcaSchema.emp where empno = empID; 
>END$$
>DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Please help me figure out what wrong I am doing. Pardon me if it seems a lil' naive. I've looked around for solution, but haven't been able to resolve it . ...

Comment: @eggyal : oh ! my bad !!  that's actually a typo. I've got the code just as you stated above, still doesn't work thoug!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getEmpName`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getEmpName`(IN `empID` VARCHAR(30), OUT `eName` VARCHAR(30)) 
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('NAME: ' , `empID`) INTO `eName`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```

```java
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
...
cStmt = con.prepareCall("{ call `getEmpName`(?, ?) }");
cStmt.setString(1, "MYNAME");
cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
boolean hadResults = cStmt.execute();
while (hadResults) {
   rs = cStmt.getResultSet();
   hadResults = cStmt.getMoreResults();
}
String outputValue = cStmt.getString(2);
...
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getEmpName`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getEmpName`(IN `p_empID` INT, OUT `p_eName` VARCHAR(30)) 
BEGIN
    SELECT `ename` INTO `p_eName`
    FROM `mcaSchema`.`emp`
    WHERE `empno` = `p_empID`; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Did a copy/paste of your demonstration program but it still isn't working !! In case it helps, I've included the import statements in my question..

Comment: @user2499998: The output parameter in your stored procedure is VARCHAR: `OUT eName varchar(30)`, but you recorded it as INTEGER: `cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);`. In the body of the stored procedure never assign a value to the output parameter.

Comment: oh !! silly me !! After the correction, it still doesn't work though ...
The corrected statement goes like this: 
cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);

Comment: to rule out any error due to my code, I created a new test project and used only your demonstration code... that didn't work either. It still gave the same error.. !!

Comment: @user2499998: What driver is using to connect to the database? [Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)? [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)?

Comment: not sure which.. but here's the guide I followed to set it up ..

https://marksman.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/setting-up-mysqljdbc-driver-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @user2499998: Try to make some changes in your stored procedure, see the update of the answer.

Comment: issue still persist.... interesting though, even if i change the procedure call to one that doesn't exist, it still gives the same error: meaning the statement  `cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call getEmpName(?, ?)}");`  **AND** `cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call getEmpNameSSSS(?, ?)}");  ` gives the same error .....

Comment: @user2499998: OK, it is clear then that the problem is not the stored procedure.